# Is there a way to automatically add a filter created on Jira to another filter?

Tags: filter, jira

I create a filter on Jira each release with a specific text, the filter is created based on a new label added on the tasks included in that release, what I need is, to create a filter for the releases, were each newly created filter (Release) is automatically added there, how can this be done using Jira?

I didn't try anything yet, I just need to know if this is doable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doable. Because you can't check automatically if a new filter was created.